# Context free languages invariant by "shuffling" right hand side

Tags: context-free, reference-request

Given a grammar $G$ for a Context Free language $L$, we can augment it by "shuffling" the right hand side of each production, e.g.:

$A \to BCD$ is expanded to $A \to BCD \; | \; BDC \; | \; CBD \; | CDB \; | \; DBC \; | \; DCB$

It may happen that the resulting language $L'$ generated by the expanded $G'$ is equal to $L$

For example:

```
Source               Shuffled
S -> XA | YB         S -> XA | AX | YB | BY
A -> YS | SY         A -> YS | SY
B -> XS | SX         B -> XS | SX
X -> 1               X -> 1
Y -> 0               Y -> 0
```

> Is there a name for such class of grammars ($L(G) = L(G_{\text{shuffled}}))$?

> <strike>Furthermore, does this theorem hold</strike>?

**Theorem [it doesn't hold, see Yuval's answer and comments]:** If exists a grammar $G$ such that, $L(G) = L(G_{\text{shuffled}})$, then for all $G'$ such that $L(G) = L(G')$ we have $L(G') = L(G'_{\text{shuffled}})$

In other words the "shuffle invariance" of grammars also corresponds to a class of languages.

Comment: It's not really a class of languages (at least the way you defined it). It's a class of grammars.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: perhaps you're right, I'll expand the question

Answer (score 2):

Your theorem doesn't hold.

Consider the grammar

$$
\begin{align}
&S \to 1T \mid T1 \\
&T \to 23 \mid 32 \\
\end{align}
$$

Shuffling the grammar results in the same language.

Now consider instead the grammar
$$
S \to 123 \mid 132 \mid 231 \mid 321
$$
which generates the same language.

Shuffling this grammar results in a larger language.

Comment: Nice! Do you also know if the invariant grammars have an "official" name?

Comment: It also would be interesting if the theorem doesn't hold also for grammars restricted to Chomsky normal form (I'll think about it)

Comment: I'm not a big expert on grammars, unfortunately.

Comment: @Vor I believe Yuval's example can be extended to grammars in Chomsky normal form. His first example basically is in ChNF, except for adding additional productions for terminals $X_a\to a$ for $a=1,2,3$. It can be shuffled. The language from the example basically forbids an $1$ in between $2,3$. Now consider $S\to A3$, $A\to 12$. These two productions mimick $S\to 123$ from the second example, but shuffling *will* bring the $1$ inside $23$.

Comment: @HendrikJan: nice!